# Solution of $2$ differential equations with $2$ dependent variables.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, self-learning

The question simply asks to find the solution of differential equations $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2y+z$ and $\frac{dz}{dx}=3y$ that satisfy the relation:

a)  $(y + z)e^{3x} = k$

b)  $(3y + z)e^{-3x} = k$

c)  $(3y + z)e^{3x} = k$

d)  $(y - z)e^{3x} = k$

---

I began by integrating the second *differential equation* $w.r.t.x$  and got

$$ z = 3xy$$

and substituted this into the first equation and integrated again $\text{w.r.t. } x$
$$y = 2yx + \frac{3yx^{2}}{z}$$

I do not know how to proceed from here.

**NB**: This isn't a homework question. Practicing for an examination

Comment: You can't just integrate the second equation like that since $y$ is also a function of $x$.

Comment: hint...differentiate the first equation and substitute for $\frac{dz}{dx}$

Comment: @DavidQuinn I used your tip and arrived at : $y'' -2y'-3y=0$. Solving that, I got the general solution as $y = Ae^{2x} + Be^{-3x}$   . But what do i do from here?

Comment: substitute $y$ in the second equation with the solution you found and integrate to find $z$

Comment: @Vasya After substitution and integration I got $z = \frac{Ae^{2x}}{2} - \frac{Be^{-3x}}{3}$

Comment: @Kalvin: you've made a mistake finding $y$, it should be $y=Ae^{-x}+Be^{3x}$

Comment: @Vasya Yes you are right. i substituted and got the final answer as $y-z = 4Be^{-3x}$ i.e option d ?

Comment: @Kalvin: what do you get for $z$? I do not see an option that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$y''-2y'-3y=0\implies y=Ae^{-x}+Be^{3x}$$

$$\frac{dz}{dx}=3y=3Ae^{-x}+3Be^{3x}\implies z=-3Ae^{-x}+Be^{3x}+C$$

Then

$$3y+z=4Be^{3x}+C\implies(3y+z)e^{-3x}=k$$

where $k=4B+Ce^{-3x}$